# KQL Azure Workbook: Filtering AppInsights cross-resource query by subscription

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

I want to filter ApplicationInsights resources by a workbook parameter for subscriptions set in the Azure Workbook. I don't see documentation on how to do this, does anyone have a solution?

My cross-resource query takes the following form. I need to filter by subscriptionId and there is no parameter to do so on the resulting table, how do I filter in this way?

```
union withsource=SourceApp 
app('Contoso-app1').requests,  
app('Contoso-app2').requests, 
app('Contoso-app3').requests, 
app('Contoso-app4').requests, 
app('Contoso-app5').requests 
| parse SourceApp with * "('" applicationName "')" *  
| where success = False
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In legacy application insights instance the `appName` property of any telemetry item has the following structure:

```
/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appInsightsName>
```

However, as you and I found out, sometimes the `appName` just reflects the name instead of the resource id. Anyway, when it is filled properly it can be used to get what you want.

By using the `split()` function we can extract the subscriptionId and create a filter using `where` like this:

```
union withsource=SourceApp 
app('Contoso-app1').requests,  
app('Contoso-app2').requests, 
app('Contoso-app3').requests, 
app('Contoso-app4').requests, 
app('Contoso-app5').requests 
| parse SourceApp with * "('" applicationName "')" *
| extend subscription = split(appName, "/")[2]
| where subscription == "<a subscriptionId>"
```

Workspace based application insights instances have a property `_ResourceId` that can be used, instead of `appName`. If you are using a legacy instance, [convert it to a Workspace based application insights instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource) and new(!) log entries will get this `_ResourceId` property:

```
union withsource=SourceApp 
app('Contoso-app1').requests,  
app('Contoso-app2').requests, 
app('Contoso-app3').requests, 
app('Contoso-app4').requests, 
app('Contoso-app5').requests 
| parse SourceApp with * "('" applicationName "')" *
| extend subscription = split(_ResourceId, "/")[2]
| where subscription == "<a subscriptionId>"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but the appName property does not look like /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appInsightsName> it just lists the name of the application insights instance @Peter Bons

Comment: @JohnFisher strange, I see different results, my newer ai instances do have this field filled as showed, older ones don't. Sometimes I see the `_ResourceId` column having the same value. Can you see if you have this one ? `app('Contoso-app5').requests | project _ResourceId`

Comment: @JohnFisher, when moving to a workspace based AI you get the `_ResourceId` as mentioned in my previous comment. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to go that direction.